# Google Cloud Functions v2 - is it possible to define function resources (such as memory) progammatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, memory-management, google-cloud-functions

I haven't been able to find anything on this, but it seems like it must exist as having to configure this via console isn't great.

I want to configure the appropriate memory allocation per function that is provisioned to Google Cloud Functions. I know it can be changed from defaults via two methods:

1. On the Cloud Function webpage for the given function, after the function has been deployed.
2. During command-line deployment if you use `gcloud functions deploy` but seemingly not if you use `firebase deploy`, such as...

```
gcloud functions deploy myFunc --memory=128MB
```

But it seems like there should be a way to provision this via a JSON configuration along side the code itself, or something similar. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes sure!! With the gcloud command, add the parameter `--log-http`. You will see the HTTP calls and the JSON body added to perform the expected operation!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Are you saying that this JSON body can be added somewhere in the project and will be submitted upon `firebase deploy`? Or that I would have to write something custom to call alongside my own JSON to call that HTTP endpoint with that JSON body?

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that you used firebase... But you can specify that in your code. Not ideal to bind the runtime configuration with your code, but it's the way Firebase works: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Comment: Ooo yeah, that's definitely weird. I would have assumed they'd allow a configuration file along side the actual code that would just be used by `deploy`. Thanks for that, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest that exists is what the commenter mentions above, which would look something like this...

```
exports.myFunction = onTrigger(
  {
    minInstances: 5,
    maxInstances: 10,
    timeoutSeconds: 180,
    memory: "512MB",
    cpu: 2
  },
  (event) => {
    // cloud function body
  }
);
```

See reference page starting at this section:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#min-max-instances